# S3 Object upload to a private bucket using a pre-signed URL result in Access denied

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm learning AWS and with my limited knowledge of AWS, am I right in saying that If I make pre-signed URLS to Upload and Download from a bucket - which is set to block all public access it should work? I take all my authentication and checks through API gateway, so if a user is able to hit the endpoint that returns a pre-signed URL to upload/download, then they are allowed to do so.

If I'm correct then I am confused to why I'm getting an `Access denied` error when I try to upload an image to my bucket (which blocks public access) via a pre-signed URL - it works perfectly when the bucket is set to public?

My Lambda function that creates a pre-signed URL:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

// Main entry point
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const result = await getUploadURL()
   // console.log('Result: ' result)
    return result;
}

const getUploadURL = async function(){
    const randomID = parseInt(Math.random()*10000000000)

    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: process.env.UploadBucket,
        Key: `${randomID}.jpg`,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    console.log('getUploadURL: ', s3Params)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Get signed URL
        resolve({
            "statusCode": 200,
            "isBase64Encoded": false
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "uploadURL": s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params),
                "photoFilename": `${randomID}.jpg`
            })
        })
    });
}
```

My python code that get's pre-signed URL and uses it to upload objects:

```
def upload_file_new(fileDir):
    presignedURL = requests.get('<URL>').json()['uploadURL']
    data = open(fileDir, 'rb').read()
    result = requests.put(presignedURL, data=data, headers={'Content-type': 'image/jpeg'})
```

My policy for my lambda function:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::contentsync/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try removing the headers

Comment: @jellycsc didn’t work, I tried that before posting this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your bucket has `Block all public access` turned on. Therefore, you cannot set the ACL of the object to `public-read`. The solution is that you can either turn off the `Block all public access` or change `public-read` to `private`.

Comment: How would I keep the option ‘Block all public access’ on for my bucket? There’s no point having signed urls to access and upload objects to a bucket that’s public? What’s ‘public-read’

Comment: @Nathan If you have `Block all public access` turned off, it doesn't necessarily mean that all your objects in the bucket suddenly become public. Instead, it means that it allows you to have a bucket policy or ACL that grants anonymous access to **some** of the objects in the bucket.

Comment: @Nathan You can learn more about `public-read` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#canned-acl).

Comment: @Nathan If you want to let users access the object via presigned URL as well, there is no point to set the ACL to `public-read`. You should just keep it `private` to prevent it from being accessed anonymously.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll take a look. So what’s your preferred way to go about this using preisgned URLS then?

Comment: @Nathan As I said above, I recommend setting the ACL to `private` if you want to let users access the object via presigned URL as well.

Comment: Yep, setting ACL to `private` is the way. You can't create a public object inside private bucket.